# var dump resizeFromImageName is giving NULL

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am generating image cache by following code

```
                    $resizeImage = $objectManager->get('\Magento\MediaStorage\Service\ImageResize');                 
                    $galleryImages = $newProduct->getMediaGalleryImages();
                    if ($galleryImages) 
                    {
                    foreach ($galleryImages as $image) {
                    $resizeImage->resizeFromImageName($image->getFile());
                    }
}
```

But no image cache is generating. When i var_dump $resizeImage->resizeFromImageName($image->getFile()); it is giving null.

Answer (score 0):

May be below code help you.

```
public function __construct(            
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,         
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory         ,
          ...
        ) {         
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;               
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;         
         ...
        }

    public function resize($image, $width = null, $height = null)
    {
        $absolutePath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('custom_module/posts/').$image;
        if (!file_exists($absolutePath)) return false;
        $imageResized = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('resized/'.$width.'/').$image;
        if (!file_exists($imageResized)) { // Only resize image if not already exists.
            //create image factory...
            $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();         
            $imageResize->open($absolutePath);
            $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);         
            $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);         
            $imageResize->keepFrame(FALSE);         
            $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);         
            $imageResize->resize($width,$height);  
            //destination folder                
            $destination = $imageResized ;    
            //save image      
            $imageResize->save($destination);         
        } 
        $resizedURL = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'resized/'.$width.'/'.$image;
        return $resizedURL;
  }
```

Ref : https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/resize-custom-image-in-magento-2/